# PHP: how to make a sum inside a "for each" cycle?

Tags: php, foreach, sum

I've made a foreach loop that print some variables found in an xml file:

```
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row)
{
    echo $row["price"] . " " . $row["product"] . "</br>";
}
```

I would like to get the sum of all the "prices" shown. How can i do?

Comment: do you mean sum, as in the value will be the same for each iteration, or do you mean a running total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a variable add up those values as you iterate:

```
$total = 0; // start with zero
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row)
{
    $total += $row["price"]; // add price to total
    echo $row["price"] . " " . $row["product"] . "</br>";
}
echo $total; // echo out total amount
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the count in a variable:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row) {
  echo $row["price"] . " " . $row["product"] . "</br>";
  $total += $row['price']; // assumed row_price is some integer
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add it to a new variable:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row) {
  echo $row["price"] . " " . $row["product"] . "<br />";
  $sum += $row["price"];
}

echo $sum . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum = 0; 
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row)
{
    echo $row["price"] . " " . $row["product"] . "</br>";
    $sum += $row["price"] ;
}

echo $sum ;
```

isnt that simple ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum=0;
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row)
    {
        echo $row["price"] . " " . $row["product"] . "</br>";
        $sum +=$row["price"];
    }
echo $sum;
```

just try this code!!